# Problems with Dual Boot, Computer not starting

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I was trying dual boot installation of Ubuntu over Windows 10. After starting the installation of Ubuntu, something weird happened and the computer shut down. Now I am trying to restart the system but it isn't booting since then. PLease help

Comment: I would suggest you would describe a bit better what the situation is, what bootmanager are you using, what happened? Was there an error? Can you still boot into one of the 2 OSs?

Comment: just boot to the usb you used to try to install ubuntu and open a terminal by typing `ctrl`+`alt`+`T`, then paste this command into it : `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y boot-repair boot-info` a program will open up that will attempt to repair things. follow the steps and when it's done just reboot. you will be greeted by grub bootloader and you should be able to choose windows and boot to it. you'll need to re-run the ubuntu installer to make the actual ubuntu install I don't think the bits of ubuntu you have are usable.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I was installing Ubuntu using a USB flash drive. I didn't realize this at that time but the battery was low and it shut down while installing. Now when I start the laptop it only shows a black screen and doesn't boot to any of the 2 OSs.

Comment: @KaranAnand comments aren't actually for prolonged discussions, but I would suggest you use a windows install usb to repair the windows part, and after you got that working, install ubuntu again. I wouldn't expect a bricked system, unless the power off happened during writing partition tables(and even then you can fix it).